# How can I download Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift

I've been trying to get my hands on Swift, but I can't seem to find it.  Is it released yet?  If not, when will it be released?

Answer (score 1):

To use Swift, download Xcode 6 and start using it to develop iOS 8 apps.  Mac apps will become available with the release of Yosemite. More resources are available here: https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/

Comment: I have Xcode 6 downloaded, but I don't see the option where I'm supposed to select Swift as the language?

Comment: You need the Xcode 6 meta not the one from the App Store

Answer (score 1):

Just open Xcode 6, click on new project, select single view project (or any of your choice), next screen select Swift as your programming language. See the `Language` dropdown in the screenshot below.
[image: screenshot of New Project in Xcode]

Answer (score 1):

Go to xcode, select new project, then applications(choose the types), click next.
Choose options for new project and in language section where it is Objective C by-default, click onto it and select swift.
Rest all the steps are same as Objective C project.

Then all you need is o learn the syntax of swift and get your hand dirty.

Also, swift brings you the new feature known as "**Playground**":- A playground is an interactive Swift coding environment that evaluates each statement and displays results as updates are made, without the need to create a project. You just have to xcode-File-New-Playground, then name of the project. For platform, if you are developing for mobile applications, choose-iOS, for Mac choose OS X and for apple tv select tvOS.

Answer (score 1):

Swift is widely available and open sourced.

- https://developer.apple.com/swift/
- https://swift.org/getting-started/

You can program on the iPad, macOS and other os have it ready to install and source code available. The REPL ships on macOS so you don’t need Xcode, but it adds tons of resources and tools and is free on the Mac App Store for anyone to use without cost.